# How to import Xen XVA files into KVM/QEMU

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, xen

I am looking at powering down some Citrix XEN systems as part of an infrastructure upgrade and I was looking into using KVM/QEMU as the hypervisor instead of Xen.

My XEN backup files are in XVA format.  Is there any easy way to run them in the KVM environment?

I have looked at the documentation for virt-v2v which looks like it is used for this kind of task but it does not seem to have any support for the XVA format.  Are there any other tools which do?

Comment: I would have asked that on U+L or serverfault See for instance: https://serverfault.com/questions/483634/how-to-import-xenservers-ovf-ova-xva-format-to-kvm Here is one specific for Ubuntu: http://chrisschell.de/2015/03/16/migrating-a-vm-from-xen-to-kvm.html

Comment: @Rinzwind The serverfault.com article is what let me to virt-v2v and the discovery that it did not support Xen images.   The chrisschell article doesn't use virt-v2v but looks interesting although very fragile process.   I was hoping for a more supported solution.